# I need to make an @ using cons in OCAML

Tags: ocaml

My teacher says we cant use appends @ in our program so im going to write my own recursive function for it.

Here is what i have so far:

(*my own appends function*)

```
let rec appends a b = 
    match a with
    | [] -> b
    | hd::[]-> hd::b
    | hd::tl-> (what i need help on)
    ;;
```

im not sure how to add just the last element of a to b if a is a list with multiple elements and then call appends on the first part since you can only remove the first element of a list with the ::
any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Something that might help is to think more functionally, i.e., to think of the code as a definition of what it means in principle to append two lists. This is as opposed to thinking of the code as a set of actions to be performed. Sometimes this helps, especially when coding in a functional language.

So, your first case says: if `a` is empty, the result of appending `a` and `b` is just `b` itself.

Your second case says: if `a` is a list of one element `hd`, the result of appending `a` and `b` is a list that consists of `hd` added to the beginning of `b`.

You're looking for a general definition for appending that works for any non-empty list `a`. The key insight is that your definition can be recursive, i.e., it can use your `appends` function.

So here is a proposed definition: if `a` is a list whose head is `hd` and whose tail is `tl`, the result of appending `a` and `b` is a list whose head is `hd` and whose tail is `tl` appended to `b`.

(This in fact gives the whole thing away. I hope it doesn't spoil the exercise for you.)

Comment: To add to this, it also helps to understand what the types are for all the variables involved and what the goals of the function is. `appends` is a function that appends two lists `a` and `b` and returns a list. `hd` is the head item of list `a` and `tl` is the tail list. Case 1 is combining an empty list with some list `b`. Case 2 is combining some item `hd` with a list `b`. Case 3 should combine some item `hd` with some list `tl` and another list `b`. We know how to combine items with lists but we have two lists... how can we make those two lists one list?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but consider that `[1; 2; 3]` is a syntactic convenience for `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: []`. If you wanted to append `[4; 5; 6]` to `[1; 2; 3]` you need to replace the `[]` with `[4; 5; 6]`.

You need to turn `append [1; 2; 3] [4; 5; 6]` into `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: [4; 5; 6]`.

If I just wanted to write an identity function for a list, it'd look like:

```
let rec list_id lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> x :: list_id xs
```

Now, you just need to pass in a second list, and have the base case return that instead. A locally scoped recursive function with access to `b` solves this nicely.

```
let append a b =
  let rec aux = function
    | [] -> b
    | x::xs -> x :: aux xs
  in
  aux a
```